# Correct way to parse eterogeneous arrays of data

Tags: android, kotlin

I have this model that I would like to parse from `JSON`:

```
class CFInsertedValuesStructure {


    @SerializedName("id")
    val id : Int? = null

    @SerializedName("value")
    val value : List<String> = listOf();


    @SerializedName("field_id")
    val field_id : String? = null
 

}
```

There is a problem with the parameter `"value"` because it isn't always an array of `String`, sometimes it could be just a `String` type.
So when happens I would like to recognise it and create an array of just one String.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

depending on what library you use the json parsing it may require a custom parsing type e.g. for `kotlinx.serialization` you might need to do something like a custom serializer

https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization/blob/master/docs/serializers.md#specifying-serializer-on-a-property

better still : tell you server-side developer it should always be an array!